# NSIS: What is a registry?

Tags: registry, nsis

What is a registry in NSIS? How do you write to and read from a registry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean the Windows Registry, which you are able to modify with NSIS?

In this case, this article may help you to clarify something: [What is the Windows Registry?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)

After that, you are able to understand and use the NSIS-Commands

```
WriteRegStr
ReadRegStr
```

A detailed example can be found here: [ReadRegStr](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.2.12) and here: [WriteRegStr](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.2.16)

Answer (score 3):

Or, you might be referring to the NSIS **Registers** which are standard variables used by some functions and plug-ins to pass or return values.

From the [NSIS Scripting Reference](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.2.2) section 4.2.2:

> *$0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8,
>   $9, $R0, $R1, $R2, $R3, $R4, $R5, $R6,
>   $R7, $R8, $R9*
>
> Registers. These variables can be used
>   just like user variables, but are
>   usually used in shared functions or
>   macros. You don't have to declare
>   these variables, so you won't get any
>   name conflicts when using them in
>   shared code. When using these
>   variables in shared code, it's
>   recommended that you use the stack to
>   save and restore their original
>   values. These variables can also be
>   used for communication with plug-ins,
>   because they can be read and written
>   by the plug-in DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [Windows registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_registry). An example on reading and writing it from NSIS is the [first result here](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=nsis+read+write+registry&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)